# a big O question: Is log_c(n) always = O(n^(1/c'))?

Tags: math, big-o, logarithm

Is this statement always true?

*log<sub>c</sub>n = O(n<sup>1/c'</sup>)*

for *c* and *c'* being any constant number greater than 0.

How can we prove the question? Will *n<sup>1/c'</sup>* always be "above" *log<sub>c</sub>(n)* in the graph when *n* approaches infinity?

Thank you.